# Not getting full response in swift HTTP request?

Tags: swift, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-directions-api

I'm using google directions API. When i send the request i'm getting half of the response.
This is my code:

```
func getDirections(_ origin: String!, destination: String!, completionHandler: @escaping ((_ status: String, _ success: Bool) -> Void)) {
        if let originLocation = origin {
            if let destinationLocation = destination {
                //var directionsURLString = baseURLDirections + "origin=" + "\(6.935299),\(79.880783)" + "&destination=" + "\(6.909411),\(79.894254)" + "&mode=driving"
                var directionsURLString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&key=YOUR_API_KEY"

                directionsURLString = directionsURLString.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

                let directionsURL = URL(string: directionsURLString)

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    let directionsData = try? Data(contentsOf: directionsURL!)

                    var error: NSError?
                    NSLog("json: \(JSON(directionsData!))")



                })
            }
            else {
                NSLog("dest nil:")
                completionHandler("Destination is nil.", false)
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Origin nil:")
            completionHandler("Origin is nil", false)
        }
    }
```

Response that i'm getting is below:

```
"routes" : [
    {
      "bounds" : {
        "northeast" : {
          "lat" : 41.8781139,
          "lng" : -87.6297872
        },
        "southwest" : {
          "lat" : 34.0523559,
          "lng" : -118.2435736
        }
      },
      "summary" : "I-55 S and I-44",
      "warnings" : [

      ],
      "copyrights" : "Map data ©2017 Google, INEGI",
      "waypoint_order" : [
        0,
        1
      ],
      "legs" : [
        {
          "via_waypoint" : [

          ],
          "distance" : {
            "value" : 932596,
            "text" : "579 mi"
          },
          "start_location" : {
            "lat" : 41.8781139,
            "lng" : -87.6297872
          },
          "traffic_speed_entry" : [

          ],
          "start_address" : "Chicago, IL, USA",
          "end_address" : "Joplin, MO, USA",
          "end_location" : {
            "lat" : 37.0842313,
            "lng" : -94.51348499999999
          },
          "duration" : {
            "value" : 30893,
```

Half of it is not printing on the console.What's the reason for that??

Comment: Is it just not printing or are you not receiving it? Try setting a breakpoint where you print and look at the variable in the inspector instead of printing it.

Comment: You are getting full response, it's not half. The print() method sometime doesn't print long JSON data correctly on the console. For confirming you can debug it in debug window.

Comment: ya, initially I print status, which is printed a value as OK even it doesn't show above. but i tried to print "way_pointArray" which was null.

Comment: i put my answer below please check i hope it would be helpful for you i am getting the whole response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this!

```
var session = URLSession()
override init() {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
}

func getDirections(_ origin: String!, destination: String!, completionHandler: @escaping ((_ status: String, _ success: Bool) -> Void)) {

    var directionsURLString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
    directionsURLString = directionsURLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
    let weatherRequestUrl = URL(string: directionsURLString)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: weatherRequestUrl!)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil && data != nil else {

            completionHandler("Your message here",false)
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
            if httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }
        }
        do {
            let dataDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

            print("Response dictionary is:\(dataDictionary)")
            completionHandler("your message here",false)
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error = \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completionHandler("Your message here",false)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: @Anushka Madushan if Answer is perfect working please Upvote so this is  useful for other user also.